# Eclipse Plugins for Python Development?

Tags: python, eclipse

Specifically looking for an Eclipse for python development (other than PyDev). Ideally something lightweight with support for auto-formatting, syntax highlighting, and PEP8 lint. I've used PyDev for a long time, but they seem to have abandoned official Eclipse support in favor of LiClipse. I also develop C++ using CDT (so I'd prefer an Eclipse-based solution).

Comment: I find that Pydev is not abandoned at all... and the author is quite responsive to bug @fabio-zadrozny can you chime in?

Comment: Where did you see that they seem to have abandoned official Eclipse support in favor of LiClipse?

Comment: What about [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) ? You can start  using the community edition version.

Comment: I understand that you want to continue to use Eclipse because you are familiar with it. I use it for C/C++ and PHP and AngularJS. BUT, I strongly prefer PyCharm. Please, do give a try. I think that you won’t regret it. @FajriAbdillah why not post an answer, explaining the best features of PyCharm?

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to find plugins for python development in eclipse but couldn't find any, but i would really recommend Komodo IDE or komodo edit (free) i am using it for quite time now and it hasn't stopped to impress me. 
It support all the features you seek i.e. auto-formatting, very nice syntax highlighting and linting as well. 
not only this Komodo IDE also gives you console like the one in eclipse to run your code within the IDE itself no need to switch to terminal to run code and back to ide again.
Here is the [complete feature list](http://komodoide.com/features/) in new Komodo ide and edit i think it is worth a try and far better than PyDev.

if you don't necessarily want IDE well then sublime text and atom text editor can also be considered.
sublime supports python linitng, syntax highlighting, auto-formatting and minimap as well same goes for atom text editor which is completely free made with <3 by github.

> EDIT:

You can also try [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) developed by Microsoft, it's free and has an excellent intellisense feature along with all the features mentioned above.